# New environment with a glyph before its head

Tags: amsthm, thmtools

I want to create the following `exercise` environment, for exercises:

[image: exercise]

That is, insert a `black triangle right` symbol, ▸, before the header of the exercise.

To accomplish this, I would prefer to use the two packages [`amsthm`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) together with [`thmtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) and its `declaretheoremstyle` command.

In the `thmtools` manual, subsection 1.3.1, they say that

> There is one important thing you cannot see in this example: there are more keys you can pass to
> \declaretheoremstyle[.]

(other than

- spaceabove, spacebelow
- headfont
- notefont, notebraces
- bodyfont
- postheadspace
- qed
  )

So, is there such a key that prepends a glyph to the header?

I am not familiar with plain TeX, and therefore can't answer my own question just by looking at the `dtx` and `sty` files of the [package repository](https://github.com/muzimuzhi/thmtools).

So that a MWE would be

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
⟨insert glyph before head key = value is ▸⟩
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{exercise}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Prime numbers}
Lorem ipsum
\section{Dolor sit amet}
Consectetur adipiscing elit.

\begin{exercise}[Euclid]
Prove that for every prime $p$, there is a prime $p^\prime > p$. In particular, the list of primes, $2, 3, 5, 7, \ldots$ , is infinite.
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `headformat`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,thmtools}

\newfontfamily{\miscsymbols}{Symbola}[
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*,
]

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headformat={\miscsymbols▸} \NAME\ \NUMBER\NOTE,
]{mystyle}

\declaretheorem[
  style=mystyle,
]{exercise}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Prime numbers}
Lorem ipsum
\section{Dolor sit amet}
Consectetur adipiscing elit.

\begin{exercise}[Euclid]\label{euclid}
Prove that for every prime $p$, there is a prime $p' > p$.
In particular, the list of primes, $2, 3, 5, 7, \dotsc$ is infinite.
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

I defined a special font because Latin Modern hasn't that particular glyph. Of course you can also use `$\blacktriangleright$` instead of a glyph from another text font.

[image]

`\NOTE` is smart and will print nothing if the optional argument is missing in a statement.

Unrelated, but typing `p'` is easier than `p^{\prime}` and yields the same result. Use `\dotsc` from `amsmath` instead of `\ldots` in that context.

Comment: The dot after `\NOTE` is bold. Is it OK? Is it not better to put also `\NOTE` in bold?

Comment: @CarLaTeX That's standard `amsthm`

Comment: OK, if it is the standard I don't say nothing :D

Answer (score 3):

This is possible directly with `amsthm`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exer}{$\blacktriangleright$ Exercise}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
Some text
\begin{exer}
 Content of exercise.
\end{exer}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of example code]

Comment: Silly me. Certainly a way to do that.